# Windows bulk rename middle filename via CLI?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, rename

**Original Files**

```
File 15 - Example.txt
File 2 - Example.txt
File 22 - Example.txt
File 3 - Example.txt
File 4 - Example.txt
File 5 - Example.txt
```

**Desired Output**

```
File 15 - Example.txt
File 02 - Example.txt
File 22 - Example.txt
File 03 - Example.txt
File 04 - Example.txt
File 05 - Example.txt
```

Single file can be renamed easily with `ren`.

```
ren "File 2 - Example.txt" "File 02 - Example.txt"
```

Would it be possible to bulk rename it with Windows `ren` or `rename` tool?

Comment: Nice Free utility to make this type of task easy....https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php

Comment: I agree. I can name plenty of GUI based solutions for this, and wonder why the insistence on CLI

Comment: @Mawg, can u do scripting with those GUI tools?

Comment: I could - using AutoIt - but would probably recommend against it :-) I just wondered if there was a hard requirement for CLI, and now it seems like there is. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Would it be possible to bulk rename it with Windows ren or rename tool?

Yes, but it requires a batch file.

test.cmd:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4" %%i in ('dir /b *Example.txt') do (
  rem pad 2nd token with leading zero
  set _num=0%%j
  set _num=!_num:~-2!
  ren "%%i %%j %%k %%l" "%%i !_num! %%k %%l"
  )
endlocal
```

example:

```
> dir *Example.txt
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test\test

03/01/2019  11:30                 0 File 15 - Example.txt
03/01/2019  11:30                 0 File 2 - Example.txt
03/01/2019  11:30                 0 File 22 - Example.txt
03/01/2019  11:30                 0 File 3 - Example.txt
03/01/2019  11:30                 0 File 4 - Example.txt
03/01/2019  11:30                 0 File 5 - Example.txt
               6 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  1,075,134,230,528 bytes free

> ..\test

> dir
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test\test

03/01/2019  11:54    <DIR>          .
03/01/2019  11:54    <DIR>          ..
03/01/2019  11:30                 0 File 02 - Example.txt
03/01/2019  11:30                 0 File 03 - Example.txt
03/01/2019  11:30                 0 File 04 - Example.txt
03/01/2019  11:30                 0 File 05 - Example.txt
03/01/2019  11:30                 0 File 15 - Example.txt
03/01/2019  11:30                 0 File 22 - Example.txt
               6 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  1,075,134,230,528 bytes free
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Dir - list files and folders - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [For - Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [variable substring - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Answer (score 17):

This PowerShell one liner will expand all numbers in the file name to two places `.PadLeft(2,'0')`:
(and leave numbers with more places untouched)

```
Get-ChildItem *[0-9]*.txt|Rename-Item -NewName {([regex]::Replace($_.BaseName,'\d+',{$args[0].Value.PadLeft(2,'0')}))+$_.Extension}
```

to be on topic, wrapped in a cmd line/batch file:

```
Powershell -Nop -C "Get-ChildItem *[0-9]*.txt|Rename-Item -NewName {([regex]::Replace($_.BaseName,'\d+',{$args[0].Value.PadLeft(2,'0')}))+$_.Extension}"
```

To be on the safe side before executing the commands, append either

- `-Confirm` which asks before doing a rename
- `-WhatIf`which lists all renames it **would** execute without the parameter

just in front of the last `"`

Answer (score 3):

***Edit:*** I've just noticed this question is specifically about renaming from the command line, so it does not answer the question directly... I'll keep it for now, hoping it will be useful for others.

---

The **Total Commander** file manager has an excellent bulk rename tool. It includes many features, including rename preview, different rename masks, regular expressions, renaming files in entire folder hierarcy, and much more. At the same time, it is quite easy to use.

Here's a screenshot for demonstrating its usage:

[image: Total Commander Multi Rename Example]

Step by step:

1. [Download](https://www.ghisler.com/download.htm) and run Total Commander.
2. Nativate to the folder with the files to rename.
3. Mark the files to rename:

   - Option 1 - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> for marking all files in the folder.
   - Option 2 - Mark files one by one, using the <kbd>Space</kbd> key or mouse right click.
   - Option 3 - Open "Find Files" (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>), type `*.txt` in the "Search for" box, click "Start Search", press "Feed to listbox", then mark the files with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.
     Use this technique if you want to rename files also in inner folders.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> to open the Multi-Rename tool.
5. Set the desired values in "Search for" and "Replace with" boxes. If using a regular expression, check the RegEx box.
6. Hit "Start!".

Answer (score -2):

`ren *.bat *.txt` will work to rename extensions on all matching files retaining the other portion of the name. Could you not abuse this to run a sequence of `ren` commands?

- `ren "File *" "File 0*"`
- `ren "File 00*" "File 0*"`
- (deal with dangling remainders like `File 022 - Example.txt`

Comment: This is **NOT** helpful, did you check what your command will do? 2->0, 22->02, 15->05.

Comment: No, I don't have a Windows OS so didn't try it. But I have remembered for years that REN can do this. I meant to give a suggestion anyway.